# How can I assign a name to the intermediate container that is created when building an Docker image?

Tags: docker

How can I assign a name to the intermediate container that is created when building an Docker image (e.g., using  [`docker image build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/))?

E.g. when I run `docker build -t kaldi -f kaldi2.dockerfile .`, I see that the intermediate container is assigned a random name such as "musing_mahavira".

```
username@server:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND        CREATED        STATUS  PORTS  NAME
831b257dd17c   c8aa0c73486e  "/bin/sh …"    2 seconds ago  Up 23 seconds  musing_mahavira
```

With  [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), one can assign a name to the container with the `--name` option:

```
username@server:~$ docker run -d --name hello kaldi
username@server:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID      IMAGE        COMMAND     CREATED           STATUS           PORTS    NAMES
806df7f58a87      kaldi        "bash"      3 minutes ago     Up 3 minutes              hello
```

Comment: My own curiosity - What is your use case for wanting to name these intermediate containers?

Comment: @idjaw Same use case as naming a container when running it: keeping things clean. E.g. some images take a while to build, so I would prefer to have a predefined name to see which images are still building. I should add that some of those random names don't look professional, e.g. the name of one of my current intermediate containers is `cocky_villany`.

Comment: Funny enough I don't think I've seen the 'generated' names in my build steps when running the docker build. I usually always see a generated "id" for my layers. What exactly are you doing that is generating those names. I just ran a test, and this is mine: https://pastebin.com/21hsmMEi

Comment: @idjaw You can view the name of the  intermediate container by running `docker ps` while the image is being built.

Comment: I'm really inclined to think this is not possible, especially since it is temporary...the names should not really matter. Also, considering that you want to always make your dockerfile as efficient as possible, you want to minimize as many layers as possible, so if this was somehow possible, you are adding an extra step that removes that much optimization.

Comment: I created a Dockerfile like `FROM alpine:3.4
RUN sleep 601` and built it several times concurrently.  Then I ran `docker container ls --filter ancestor=sha256:c7fc7faf8c28d48044763609508ebeebd912ad6141a722386b89d044b62e4d45` and it only showed the intermediate containers.  I suspect what you really want is a filter that does the reverse - only show containers that are not intermediate containers.  I have no idea if my hack actually works (besides it being the opposite of desired).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, naming during the Docker container building is impossible.

To specify a name for a container use `--name` argument when you launch the container, or rename a running container to something more descriptive.

```
docker rename container_name specify_name
```

Comment: The intermediate containers will not exist post build. So the rename won't really help, unfortunately. The renaming would have be defined somehow in the dockerfile. I don't think it is possible, but I'm now trying to see if it can....it's an interesting use case.